How to separate line of text by commas in COBOL
Hello Im learning COBOL and have a text file that has a bunch of works and numbers separated by ",". I need it to stop when it hits the comma and then move to the next variable and so on. here is my file
1001,John,Doe,Engineer,85000
Heres my current code:
`
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PayRoll.
AUTHOR. TheodoreRoche.
    ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
        INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
            FILE-CONTROL.
            SELECT EMPLOYEE ASSIGN TO "COBOLT_Test_File.csv"
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
    
    DATA DIVISION.
        FILE SECTION.
        FD EMPLOYEE.
        01 EMPLOYEE-FILE.
            02 EMPLOYEE-ID PIC 9(4).
            02 FIRST-NAME PIC X(30).
            02 LAST-NAME PIC X(30).
            02 EMPLOYEE-POSITION PIC X(30).
            02 SALARY PIC 9(10).


    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        01 WS-EOF PIC A(1).
        01 WS-EMPLOYEE.
            02 WS-EMPLOYEE-ID PIC 9(4).
            02 WS-FIRST-NAME PIC X(30).
            02 WS-LAST-NAME PIC X(30).
            02 WS-EMPLOYEE-POSITION PIC X(30).
            02 WS-SALARY PIC 9(10).
            
            
    PROCEDURE DIVISION.
        OPEN INPUT EMPLOYEE.
            PERFORM UNTIL WS-EOF='Y'
                READ EMPLOYEE INTO WS-EMPLOYEE
                    AT END MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF
                    NOT AT END 
                        DISPLAY "ID #: " WS-EMPLOYEE-ID
                        DISPLAY "First Name: " WS-FIRST-NAME
                        DISPLAY "Last Name: " WS-LAST-NAME
                        DISPLAY "Position: " WS-EMPLOYEE-POSITION
                        DISPLAY "Salary: " WS-SALARY
                END-READ
            END-PERFORM.
        CLOSE EMPLOYEE.
    STOP RUN.

`
this is an example of what Im getting as an output:
ID #: 1001
First Name:  John Doe Engineer 85000
Last Name:
Position:
Salary:
Im really stuck and have tried looking online and even going to chatGPT, but Im really confused right now.

Never mind I figured It out. I was way over complicating it.
Heres is the code that works for those who come after looking for help:
    IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. PayRoll.
    AUTHOR. TheodoreRoche.
    
    ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
        INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
            FILE-CONTROL.
            SELECT EMPLOYEE-FILE ASSIGN TO "COBOLT_Test_File.csv"
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
    
    DATA DIVISION.
    FILE SECTION.
    FD EMPLOYEE-FILE.
    01 EMPLOYEE-RECORD PIC X(100).
    
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 EMPLOYEE-DATA.
       05 EMPLOYEE-ID   PIC 9(4).
       05 FIRST-NAME    PIC X(30).
       05 LAST-NAME     PIC X(30).
       05 JOB-TITLE     PIC X(30).
       05 SALARY        PIC 9(8).
    01 EOF PIC X(3).
    
    PROCEDURE DIVISION.
        OPEN INPUT EMPLOYEE-FILE
        PERFORM UNTIL EOF="YES"
            READ EMPLOYEE-FILE INTO EMPLOYEE-RECORD
            AT END
                MOVE "YES" TO EOF
            NOT AT END
                UNSTRING EMPLOYEE-RECORD DELIMITED BY ","
                INTO EMPLOYEE-ID, 
                FIRST-NAME, 
                LAST-NAME, 
                JOB-TITLE, 
                SALARY
    
                DISPLAY "Employee ID: " EMPLOYEE-ID
                DISPLAY "First Name: " FIRST-NAME
                DISPLAY "Last Name: " LAST-NAME
                DISPLAY "Job Title: " JOB-TITLE
                DISPLAY "Salary: " SALARY
                DISPLAY " "
        END-PERFORM
        CLOSE EMPLOYEE-FILE
        STOP RUN.

